# Load data from flat file to Sql Server table and also export to excel using SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

**Problem Statement**: The requirement is straight-forward, which is we have a flat file(csv basically) which we need to load into one of the tables in `Sql Server` database. The problem arises when we have to derive a new column(not present in flat file) and populate this too alongwith rest of the columns from the file.
The derivation logic of the new columns is - find the max date of "TransactionDate".

The entire exercise is to be performed in `SSIS` and we were hoping to get it done by using `DataFlowTask` but stuck on how to derive the new column and then add it to the destination flow.

**Ideas**:

1. Use `DataFlowTask` to read the file and then store it in `recordset` so that in `ControlFlow` we would use `ScriptTask` to read it as `DataTable` and use `LINQ` sort-of to determine the max column and push it to another `DataFlow` to be consumed by `Sql table` (but this I guess would require creating of `tabletype` in database which I would avoid)
2. Perform the entire operation in `DataFlowTask` itself and we would be needing `Asynchronous transformation` (to get all the data and find out the max value)

We are kind of out-of-ideas here and any lead would be much appreciated and do let us know if any further information would be required on this regard.

Comment: So every record you load from the CSV should have the same MAX Transaction date when loaded to your destination table?

Comment: @AaronHughes - that's correct, need to derive the max of TransactionDate only once for the batch and it would be same for that particular batch when loaded onto table.

Comment: Why not load the batch first, and then run an Execute SQL task to perform an update? Nothing says you can't modify the data in the table after it's been loaded.

Comment: @AaronHughes I know and that would be last attempt, as the load would be an append to the destination table and running an update would update all the rows and not the one's which are loaded for that particular batch -  to counter this we could introduce a staging table but again as I said was looking if SSIS could do the above.

Comment: Can you not limit your update statement to only update where the TransactionDate is null? I think you might be over engineering your solution here. Sure, you could use a script task and read the recordset in, save the max value to a variable and write all that to a table. But should you? Isn't it easier, and more understandable to run a dataflow and then perform the update?

Comment: @AaronHughes I think we went overboard here and made the problem way to complex. I would be happy to accept your above posted proposal as a solution if you would like to post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I posted a solution just so you can mark it closed, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a dataflow task to insert the data to your destination table. Follow that up with an Execute SQL task that calculates the `MAX(TransactionDate)` based on the values in the table with a NULL (or other new record indicator) MaxTransactionDate.